# Is it possible to read the accessibilityLabel attribute of an item using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, accessibility

I'm trying to extract the list of cookies according to Safari.

I have the following code fragment:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    keystroke "," using command down -- display preferences
    delay 1
    click button "Privacy" of toolbar 1 of window 1
    delay 2 -- let the cookie count update
    click button "Details…" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Privacy"
    get <what??> of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1 of window "Privacy"
end tell
```

Which is fine except that I can find no way to get the cookie name from the row. Tantalisingly, however, VoiceOver can read the value and Accessibility Inspector shows it to be held in the `accessibilityLabel` attribute.

Hence the question: is there a way of getting the value of the `accessibilityLabel` attribute in AppleScript?

Versions: Safari 9.0 / El Capitan.

PS: I know there is a Cookies.binarycookies file in the user's library. I'd still like the answer to my question for future reference at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the 'description' of the 'UI Element' of each row. Like so:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    keystroke "," using command down -- display preferences
    delay 1
    click button "Privacy" of toolbar 1 of window 1
    delay 2 -- let the cookie count update
    click button "Details…" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Privacy"
    set z to description of UI element 1 of every row of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1 of window "Privacy"
end tell
return z
```

Comment: "UI element" is a helpful terminology to know about.

Comment: Agreed. I knew about "UI element" -- it was 'description' that I didn't know about. I'm sure I tried 'value of', 'text of' and a few other optimistic guesses. Is 'UI Element' fully documented anywhere?

Comment: A useful trick is to: set z to properties of UI element 1 of …   You can then look at all the properties that might be useful. That's where I found the description property.